# How to do wilcox.test correctly for multiple columns with NA in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am trying to do `wilcox.test` for multiple columns against the target column, where each column has `NA` values and I need to drop it for each column independently. TO do `wilcox.test`, first I need to sample for each column then drop `NA` in current columns, then filter out the value of target column, but I am not successful to retrieve the index of `NA` in the current column, because I used `which(is.na(df$x1), arr.ind=TRUE)`, but it is not going to help me how to keep corresponding values in the target column. Because the position of `NA` in each column is different, the corresponding values of the target column are also changed. I don't know how to do this sort of manipulation in R. Can anyone point me out how to make this happen? any thought?

**reproducible example**:

here is the minimal reproducible data for my task:

```
> dput(mydf)
structure(list(v1 = c(3.69055560203349, 3.01675043088942, 3.4195128033004, 
NA, 3.5798210897553, 4.00279762977148, 3.39364072476593, 3.74902908274812, 
3.75245019598874, NA), v2 = c(8.29251175276882, 6.03085239544148, 
6.61202305724909, 6.32182430455213, 7.01468228541546, 7.91002666664165, 
8.43386943449607, 8.5247956890294, 8.052886597559, 7.22851794548592
), v3 = c(2.67156354473232, 2.36125329858185, 2.17487388876694, 
NA, 2.17995780295262, 2.0439205043448, 1.71779360521063, 2.02967258021284, 
2.04390173884486, NA), v4 = c(2.9771612602651, 2.8554942149399, 
2.86921526382523, NA, 3.5642547915086, 3.02900788965761, 2.86324542975628, 
2.8451951395453, 2.17256320516553, NA), label = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
10L))
```

**my attempt:**

I want to do sampling for each column then find out the corresponding value of the target column, then do `wilcox.test`. Here is what I tried:

```
label = mydf$label
lapply(1:5, function(i){
    res= lapply(colnames(mydf), function(x){
        col_rmna = na.omit(mydf[x])
        sample_size = floor(0.33*nrow(col_rmna))
        split_index <- sample(seq_len(nrow(col_rmna)), size = sample_size, replace = FALSE)
        feat_samped = col_rmna[split_index, ]
        label = subset(label, feat_samped[!which(is.na(feat_samped), arr.ind=TRUE),])
        wtst = wilcox.test(feat_samped ~label)$p.value
    })
    ## put the output of each itertion into list 
})
```

but I don't how to get the corresponding value of lable and do `wilcox.test` for each sampled column with its corresponding label value. My final goal is to compute average p-value of each column after multiple iterations where different sampled column values is generated.

Can anyone point me out how to make this consistent? how to look up and keep the values of the target column by looking at `NA` values in another column, where values that appeared in `NA` row are simply discarded? any idea?

**objective**:

Here I want to run multiple iterations where do sampling for each column and do `wilcox.test`, the final output would be the dataframe where the average p-value of each column should be included. how to get this done? any easier way to do this sort of task in R? thanks

Comment: your example is missing `tst` so it is not reproducible, what is your overall goal? it doesn't make sense to average p-values

Comment: @rawr sorry, it was a typo, fixed now and it worked. any further thought? thanks

Comment: i would use `replicate` instead of nested `lapply`s, and it looks like you're making this too complicated--is this what you want? `lapply(1:4, function(i) replicate(5, {mydf[, i] <- sample(mydf[, i]); mydf <- na.omit(mydf); mydf <- mydf[sample(nrow(mydf)), ]; wilcox.test(mydf[, i] ~ factor(mydf$label, 0:1))$p.value}))`

Comment: @rawr I am not complicating, but I need to treat `NA` very carefully for each column, where the proportion of `NA for each column may be different from one to another. I need to do sampling for each column then do `wilcox.test`. I tried similar way of your  doing but it wasn't right fot my analysis. Any further thought?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I make no assessment of the validity of this approach, only its programatic implementation.

We can use `which()` to convert the logical vector of which observations are not `NA`, and instead of sampling the data directly, sample the indices. That way, the indices will also match up to the position of the labels. I also took care of the case when only one of the two labels is sampled, as that would create only one factor, and `wilcox.test` would fail.

```
sample.fraction <- 0.8
trials <- 10
result <- lapply(mydf[,1:4],function(x){
  pvals <- vector();
  for(i in seq(1,trials)){
    number.non.na.obs <- length(x[!is.na(x)]);
    n.sample <- floor(sample.fraction*number.non.na.obs);
    logical.not.na <- !is.na(x);
    target.indices <- which(logical.not.na);
    sample <- sample(target.indices,n.sample);
    n.labels.sampled <- length(table(mydf$label[sample]));
    if(n.labels.sampled < 2){pvals[i] <- NA}
     else{pvals[i] <- wilcox.test(x[sample]~mydf$label[sample])$p.value}
  }
return(pvals);  
})
result
#$v1
# [1] 0.3333333 1.0000000 0.7000000 0.7000000 0.1333333 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.3333333
#$v2
# [1] 0.1142857 0.4285714 0.3428571 0.4285714 0.1142857 0.1142857 0.1428571 0.2500000 0.1428571 0.3428571
#$v3
# [1] 0.5333333 1.0000000 0.5333333 0.5333333 0.6666667 0.5333333 0.5333333 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.8000000
#$v4
# [1] 1.0000000 0.2666667 0.6666667 0.8000000 0.8000000 1.0000000 0.2666667 0.3333333 0.4000000 1.0000000
```

If you wanted the mean, you could use `sapply`.

```
sapply(result, mean)
#       v1        v2        v3        v4 
#0.5533333 0.3321429 0.7166667 0.6933333
```

**Data**

```
mydf <- structure(list(v1 = c(3.69055560203349, 3.01675043088942, 3.4195128033004, 
NA, 3.5798210897553, 4.00279762977148, 3.39364072476593, 3.74902908274812, 
3.75245019598874, NA), v2 = c(8.29251175276882, 6.03085239544148, 
6.61202305724909, 6.32182430455213, 7.01468228541546, 7.91002666664165, 
8.43386943449607, 8.5247956890294, 8.052886597559, 7.22851794548592
), v3 = c(2.67156354473232, 2.36125329858185, 2.17487388876694, 
NA, 2.17995780295262, 2.0439205043448, 1.71779360521063, 2.02967258021284, 
2.04390173884486, NA), v4 = c(2.9771612602651, 2.8554942149399, 
2.86921526382523, NA, 3.5642547915086, 3.02900788965761, 2.86324542975628, 
2.8451951395453, 2.17256320516553, NA), label = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
10L))
```

Comment: is that possible to make your code readable to understand? how to vectorize your code whereas start to use `sapply`? thanks

Comment: thanks, I need to validate and understand your output first. I'd get back to you shortly before accepting your answer.

Comment: I don't understand the use of this:  `if(length(table(mydf$label[sample])) == 1){NA}`, can you tell me what's that used for? can we use `ifelse` instead?

Comment: I want to understand or simplify this line : `n.sample <- floor(sample.fraction*length(x[!is.na(x)]))`, can we do it more readable way? thanks

Comment: do you think is there any simplified version of the above code? thanks

Comment: Is it easier to understand as a for loop?

Comment: this version is pretty intuitive to me now. Thanks a lot for your help :)